# Telemarketing through Google

Tags: contract-law, telemarketing

I'm a young independent contractor interested in selling my services to big business. Now, I know that phone numbers for local shops are provided on Google maps. So, can I say, call my local mcdonald's with number provided, ask for the main office's phone number and advertise my services there? Is this something I can do? What legal limitations will I face? If this is legally not the best choice for me, what else can I do?

Comment: Listed phone numbers are public information. You can call them with unsolicited offers until they ask you not to, though you might need to check the do not call list. I doubt that's necessary for a business phone number, though.

Comment: I hit return by mistake. See the edited comment.